# Which data can I use to draw the figure?

Tags: plotting

Please refer to the PhD thesis given at the following link:

- [Etienne Bernard. *Algorithms and applications of the Monte Carlo method : Two-dimensional melting and perfect sampling.*](https://theses.hal.science/tel-00637330/document)

I want to draw the following plot given on page 68:

[image]

---

**Figure 3.2:** Example of error estimation for the orientational correlation function of 1024^2 particles at η = 0.700. Each of the 64 simulations are independent, allowing a safe computation of the standard deviation. (Ref [6], cf. Section 7.3).

---

In Figure 3.2 the axes are labeled as follows:

- The **x-axis** represents `r/s`. This is likely a normalized time scale, where `r` could stand for a time-related variable (such as the time at which each measurement is taken) and `s` could be a scaling factor, such as the correlation time `τ`.
- The **y-axis** represents `C(r)`. This is the auto-correlation function over the normalized time scale. The auto-correlation function `C(t)` measures how the value of a variable at a certain time is related to its value at a different time.

I wrote ***likely*** and ***could*** because it is not clearly written in the given document.

The figure itself is described as "Example of error estimation for the orientational correlation function of 1024^2 particles at η = 0.700." This suggests that the data points on the graph depict the decay of the orientational correlation function as a function of scaled time for a large system of particles at a specific density (η = 0.700).

I am experimenting with the movement of protein chains.

I have the following data in my hand:

a. Center of Mass $CM$: $$ \{ (x_1, y_1, z_1), (x_2, y_2, z_2), (x_3, y_3, z_3), ... ,(x_m, y_m, z_m) \} $$
b. End-to-end distance squared $R^2$: $$\{ R^2_1, R^2_2, R^2_3, ..., R^2_n \}$$

Which data can I use to draw Figure 3.2 in the given PDF document?

Explain how.

---

**EDIT:** The following was my algorithm:

1. Read each $R^2$ file and convert each of them into an individual List
2. Compute their autocorrelations and obtain them as individual lists
3. Find a unique $R^2$ list and plot that list along x-axis
4. Plot autocorrelations along y-axis

The outcome is not promising.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What is the definition of the quantities shown on the axes of the figure?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, *What is the definition of the quantities shown on the axes of the figure?* --- I edited the OP.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, *What have you tried?* --- I have calculated $MSD$ and $D$ data from $CM$ and $R^2$. Now, I am waiting for a clue or hint.

Comment: Have you read the first paragraph on page 70, right below equation 3.19? The author explains how to discretize/construct $C_0(r)$. Which seems to require running particle simulations (64 of them). I checked the thesis quickly, I didn't see any code in it. You may have to write it yourself as described in Sections 2 and 3